# Inner products on vectors fields over $\mathbb Q$ and subfields of $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) we can't have inner products on vector spaces over finite fields. Can we have an inner product on a vector space over $\mathbb Q$? What about an inner product on vector spaces over intermediate fields between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb C$?

(Questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739980) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129413) don't make it clear to me if it's possible).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the ordinary inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle: \mathbb C^n \times \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C$ restricts nicely: for each subfield $K \subseteq \mathbb C$ which is closed under complex conjugation, we have that $\langle \cdot ,\cdot\rangle|_{K^n \times K^n}: K^n \times K^n \to K$, and it still trivially satisfies all the requirements of an inner product.

Comment: Does this mean the answer to my question is "yes", at least for the usual inner product?

Comment: What is the "usual inner product"? The dot product on finite-dimensional vector spaces with basis over a subfield of $\mathbb C$ (closed under conjugation) works fine, yeah. But for example, seeing $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space doesn't have an obvious inner product to me. (I see that there are some typos in my answer, let me correct real quick.)

Comment: You meant $K \cap \mathbb{C}$ and $\|u\|^2 \in K \cap \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @reuns, you're right. Corrected.

Comment: By "the usual inner product" I meant "the ordinary inner product" you were talking about (whatever that is)

Comment: Then yes.      $~~~~~~$